# Synonyms for video-review tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Developing [@alamoot's idea](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/875/12991), I have crawled our site and tagged bunch of questions with tags synonymous to [video-review](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-review) tag, because in different sports people use different terms for the same concept:

- [instant-replay](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instant-replay): 5 questions
- [hawk-eye](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hawk-eye): 4 questions
- [third-umpire](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/third-umpire): 2 questions
- [var](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/var): 1 question + 1 duplicate

Dear colleagues with a total answer score of [5 or more](https://sports.stackexchange.com/tags/video-review/topusers) on the tag, please consider to **[approve these synonyms](https://sports.stackexchange.com/tags/video-review/synonyms)** if you agree with suggestions.

Comment: I like what you've done here, I would've voted if I had the minimum score

Comment: Synonyms are approved, so I flagged the question to be marked with `status-completed` tag. Thanks everyone.